# why to take logs and remove mean?

Tags: data-transformation, logarithm

I am replicating a paper (Gil Kim and David Vera 2017). They transform the price of oil by doing the following;

"for the real price of oil, we first deflate it, transform it into natural log and remove the mean"

1. what is the reasoning behind removing the mean?
2. I am not sure how to do it. Should I take the mean of the whole transformed series log(oilp) and then substract the same number to each observation of the transformed series? or to the original one?

Comment: By "remove the mean" I assume they mean they subtract the mean from each value. This would in turn make the new mean equal to 0 and also the sum of all values equal to 0.

Comment: that stands if the raw data is de-meaned. he's asking about de-meaning the *log* data

Comment: Can you give full reference/link to that paper?